# SQL- Case statement with PARTITION by

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to check if an ID has more than one distinct row? In the below table `VBELN` 15233 has two `VB_TYPE`. I need to check if a `VBELN` has 'p' and 'R' then condition1 . `VBELN` 25344 has only R, so my else logic will have - if(`VBELN` does not contain p) then condition2

```
+-------+---------+
| VBELN | VB_TYPE |
+-------+---------+
| 15233 | p       |
+-------+---------+
| 15233 | R       |
+-------+---------+
| 25344 | R       |
+-------+---------+
| 26455 | p       |
+-------+---------+
| 26455 | R       |
+-------+---------+
```

I have tried with the below case statement, but I'm not able to think beyond this logic.

SQL:

```
CASE WHEN (Count(VBELN) OVER (PARTITION BY VBELN))=2  THEN CONDITION 1
     ELSE CONDITION 2
     END
```

Is there a better logic than count()?

Comment: If it's a distinct count, shouldn't it be `COUNT(DISTINCT [column])` in your `CASE` **expression**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine if the types are not repeated.

```
(CASE WHEN (Count(VBELN) OVER (PARTITION BY VBELN)) = 2
      THEN CONDITION 1
      ELSE CONDITION 2
 END)
```

If you have two types, then this is closer to what you want:

```
(CASE WHEN MIN(VB_TYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY VBELN) <> MAX(VB_TYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY VBELN)
      THEN CONDITION 1
      ELSE CONDITION 2
 END)
```

If there are other types, then the logic can be done but is a bit more complicated.